# How to position Upload button at the center of the block

Tags: html, css

Current condition of site
[image]

I want to make sure that the choose file button should be positioned at the upload image position. I am new to HTML and CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Health Buddy</title>
    <link rel= "stylesheet" href="My_css.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="TOP">HEALTH BUDDY</div>
    <div class="class">Upload Image</div>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
        <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Kindly add the CSS for the "Upload Image" `div` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the *"choose file button"* inside the *"upload image"* div. You can then [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) them to achieve what you want. Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Health Buddy</title>
    <link rel= "stylesheet" href="My_css.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        .class {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            border: 1px solid red;
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        #myFile {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            opacity: 0;
            z-index: 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="TOP">HEALTH BUDDY</div>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
        <div class="class">
            Upload Image
            <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename">
        </div>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the appropriate css attribute to the class `fullscreen table-cell valign-middle text-center`which is having a input element.

```css
body {
  margin : 0px;
}

.fullscreen {
  width : 100vw;
  height : 100vh;
}

.table-cell {
  display : table-cell;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  width : 200px;
  height :200px;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  }

.valign-middle {
  vertical-align : middle;
}

.text-center {
  text-align : center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Health Buddy</title>
    <link rel= "stylesheet" href="My_css.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="TOP">HEALTH BUDDY</div>
    <div class="fullscreen table-cell valign-middle text-center">
    <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename"></div>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```